# Gives error while trying to upload rule service in Business Rules Server, WSO2

Tags: wso2

I am trying to upload a .aar file in the management console of Business rules server, but while uploading i am getting this error: TID: [] [WSO2 BRS] [2013-02-19 18:41:29,556] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.rulecep.service.RuleCEPDeployerService} -  Can not build the service {org.wso2.carbon.rulecep.service.RuleCEPDeployerService}
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle org.apache.axis2.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle, key The operation is not valid: operation name missing 
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:374)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:334)
    at org.apache.axis2.i18n.MessageBundle.getMessage(MessageBundle.java:194)
    at org.apache.axis2.i18n.MessageBundle.getMessage(MessageBundle.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis2.i18n.Messages.getMessage(Messages.java:74)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.processOperations(ServiceBuilder.java:717)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:355)
    at org.wso2.carbon.rulecep.service.ServiceBuilder.createAxisService(ServiceBuilder.java:266)
    at org.wso2.carbon.rulecep.service.ServiceBuilder.build(ServiceBuilder.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.rulecep.service.RuleCEPDeployerService.deploy(RuleCEPDeployerService.java:77)
    at org.wso2.carbon.rule.service.RuleServiceDeployer.deploy(RuleServiceDeployer.java:69)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.Scheduler$SchedulerTimerTask.run(Scheduler.java:93)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
TID: [] [WSO2 BRS] [2013-02-19 18:41:29,572]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Can't find resource for bundle org.apache.axis2.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle, key The operation is not valid: operation name missing  {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}
TID: [] [WSO2 BRS] [2013-02-19 18:41:29,572]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Can't find resource for bundle org.apache.axis2.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle, key The operation is not valid: operation name missing  {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}

Answer (score 0):

try this method: http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/05/eclipse-plugin-wso2-business-rules-server
I used to have problems similar to yours while uploading the .aar files through the wizard, but I followed the above tutorial and it works perfectly fine.